# Getting a web-server error in Eclipse that is Usage: java javassist.tools.web.Webserver <port number>

Tags: eclipse, webserver

In Eclipse when I'm trying to run my project as java project I'm getting an error like this

> **Usage: java javassist.tools.web.Webserver**

and nothing happens. Not showing any problems or anything.

Comment: Which web server are you trying to use? By doing a web search, I found a basic walkthrough for WebLogic configuration: https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/post/weblogic-server-in-eclipse-ide-for-java-ee-developers

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are running the project with the correct **run** configurations?

I was having the same issue. For some reason (maybe because I had just updated eclipse?) eclipse decided to change my **run** to *AppletServer - javassist.tools.rmi* when I was using *Main - io.helidon.microprofile.server*.

Hopefully this may give you an insight into your issue.